# Java Bubble Sort Acting Strange

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

I have a function here for  bubble sort using Java and this code does work and sort an array. However, the issue is that I have no idea how it's sorting it because it does not seem like standard bubble sort.

```
public static void swap (int [ ] data, int index1, int index2)
// POST: elements at indexes are exchanged
{   int temp = data[index1];                                // temporary to hold first value
    data[index1] = data[index2];
    data[index2] = temp;
}

public static void bubbleSort (int [ ] data)
// POST: elements in data array are sorted in ascending order
{   for (int ct1=0; ct1<data.length-1; ct1++)           // outer loop moves one element into place
    {   for (int ct2=0; ct2<data.length-1-ct1; ct2++)
            if (data[ct2] > data[ct2+1])                    // swap if element on left bigger than right
                swap (data, ct2,ct2+1);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) System.out.print(data[i] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The bubble sort I understand would take an array `{40, 90, 10, 60, 20}` and compare the 0th and 1st index. If the 0th index is greater than the 1st index then they would swap. Then, in this case, 40 and 90 would stay where they are and then the 1st and 2nd index would be compared, resulting in 90 and 10 swapping. This would continue n - 1 times where n is the length of the array.

The problem is, using this function seems to give the output:

```
Bubble sort:
Starting array: 40 90 10 60 20 
40 10 60 20 90 
10 40 20 60 90 
10 20 40 60 90 
10 20 40 60 90
```

Can anybody help explain this please?

It seems to be comparing arbitrary values and does not check the 40 and 90 like it should.

Comment: It doesn't look to be comparing things arbitrarily.  It's doing exactly what the code has it doing.  Literally, it's "bubbling" the larger values to the end of the array.  Inside your first inner loop, set a `System.out.println`-- that might help clarify it for you.

Comment: The behaviour is matching your understanding. The output you are creating is after each line is processed not after each swap. you should use more braces.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for Kevin. If you post an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your bubbleSort method, you are starting an array from 0 upto the length of array - 1. Instead just make is simple and run it in reverse like this:

```
public static void bubbleSort(int [] data) {
    int k;
    for (int m = data.length; m >= 0; m--) {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
            k = i + 1;
            if (array[i] > array[k]) {
                swapNumbers(i, k, array);
            }
        }
      // Time to test this new array here:
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(data[i] + ", ");
    }
        System.out.println("\n");           
    }
}
```

Check if your solution is printed correctly and let me know

Answer (score 0):

it will be swap until the end in a one loop with ct2.
inside loop ,will be going 4 times .

it is like a rock falling into water.

Engilsh is poor ,sorry~

Answer (score 0):

Your bubble sort is behaving the way you expect it too.
It is sorting lowest to highest in reverse order (i.e. last column is set first)

I think the problem you are having is that the output sample frequency
does not match what is going on in your head.

if you change the code slightly

```
public static void swap (int [ ] data, int index1, int index2){
    int temp = data[index1];
    data[index1] = data[index2];
    data[index2] = temp;
}

public static void bubbleSort (int [ ] data) {
    for (int ct1=0; ct1<data.length-1; ct1++) {
        for (int ct2=0; ct2<data.length-1-ct1; ct2++) {
            if (data[ct2] > data[ct2 + 1]) {
                swap(data, ct2, ct2 + 1);
            // non functional change to move sampling point
                for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                     System.out.print(data[i] + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    bubbleSort(new int[]{40,90,10,60,20});
}
```

this produces the output

```
40 10 90 60 20 
40 10 60 90 20 
40 10 60 20 90 
10 40 60 20 90 
10 40 20 60 90 
10 20 40 60 90
```

which is what I think you expect to see.